# Swiper. Изменить pagination, вместо точек картинки(превьюшки)

Tags: swiper

Использую Swiper ( `http://idangero.us/swiper/api/` ), все настроил, все работает за исключением одного, мне вместо точек в pagination необходимо вывести картинки, чтобы получилось что-то типа этого: `https://yadi.sk/i/kQ-E0XVj3WX9hv`

Вот что я имею `https://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/ah8d8yrL/1/`
Думаю надо использовать renderBullet или renderCustom, но как не пойму?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  clickable: true,
  type : 'custom',
  bulletClass:'swiper_pagination_img'
},
```

Задай картинкам класс swiper_pagination_img и будет кликабельным. мне это помогло.

Comment: И что должно произойти? Задача была вместо точек вывести превьюшки (маленькие фотки)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ah8d8yrL/10/
Вот это должно произойти. документацию тоже иногда надо читать

Comment: Супер! Дык в том то и дело читал, видимо плохо)). Ок, тогда еще вопрос, как узнать активный слайд в превью?

Comment: И если не сложно, ткните меня в доку где написано про класс swiper_pagination_img

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ah8d8yrL/89/
Первоначально ты использовал type:'custom'
поэтому автоматическая смена класса на активную не было
как вариант использовал функцию renderCustom. Пример по ссылке

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#pagination
Читай про моменты bulletClass, bulletActiveClass и тип пагинации

Comment: Это уже видел 100 раз, но про класс swiper_pagination_img ни слова. Я в итоге сделал через renderBullet, и все четко работает. Про класс swiper_pagination_img и renderCustom возму на заметку, может где то что то когда то переделаю. Супер! Спасибо!

Comment: swiper_pagination_img этот класс я прописал в свойстве bulletClass
таким образом картинки с этим классом стали участвовать в пагинации.

Comment: Это понятно, не понятно где о нем в доке сказано, я бы про него никогда не узнал бы если не вы...

Comment: так про него и не сказано. Я просто прописал этот класс картинкам и в скрипте указал что за пагинацию отвечает объект с таким классом
  bulletClass:'swiper_pagination_img'

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную задачу с помощью создания массива картинок и их пуша в пагинацию:

```
<div class="reviews">
    <div class="reviews__container _container">
        <div class="reviews__title">Что о нас говорят?</div>
        <div class="reviews__body">
            <div class="reviews__next _icon-slider-right"></div>
            <div class="reviews__prev _icon-slider-left"></div>
            <div class="reviews__slider _swiper">
                <div class="reviews__item">
                    <div class="reviews__img">
                        <img src="img/alina.png" alt="review">
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews__text">
                        Особенно хочу отметить работника Бадурова Яниса. Работник внимательный, доброжелательный,
                        вежливый, учтивый, почитает возраст. Даёт исчерпывающую информацию по интересующим вопросам.
                        Говорит корректно, конкретно и победно. Я очень рада, что он меня обслуживает. На эту службу
                        можно положиться. Спасибо, что в самое тяжелое время вы рядом и берёте все заботы на себя.
                        Желаю вам всем огромного человеческого счастья, терпения, крепкого здоровья и долгих-долгих
                        лет жизни
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews__name">Ева Левен</div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews__item">
                    <div class="reviews__img">
                        <img src="img/alina.png" alt="review">
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews__text">
                        Особенно хочу отметить работника Бадурова Яниса. Работник внимательный, доброжелательный,
                        вежливый, учтивый, почитает возраст. Даёт исчерпывающую информацию по интересующим вопросам.
                        Говорит корректно, конкретно и победно. Я очень рада, что он меня обслуживает. На эту службу
                        можно положиться. Спасибо, что в самое тяжелое время вы рядом и берёте все заботы на себя.
                        Желаю вам всем огромного человеческого счастья, терпения, крепкого здоровья и долгих-долгих
                        лет жизни
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews__name">Ева Левен</div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews__item">
                    <div class="reviews__img">
                        <img src="img/alina.png" alt="review">
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews__text">
                        Особенно хочу отметить работника Бадурова Яниса. Работник внимательный, доброжелательный,
                        вежливый, учтивый, почитает возраст. Даёт исчерпывающую информацию по интересующим вопросам.
                        Говорит корректно, конкретно и победно. Я очень рада, что он меня обслуживает. На эту службу
                        можно положиться. Спасибо, что в самое тяжелое время вы рядом и берёте все заботы на себя.
                        Желаю вам всем огромного человеческого счастья, терпения, крепкого здоровья и долгих-долгих
                        лет жизни
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews__name">Ева Левен</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reviews__pagging"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Затем использую функцию `renderBullet` просто подставляем и всё работает:

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.reviews__img');

let sliderThumbnails = [];

sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
    sliderThumbnails.push(sliderImage.innerHTML);
});

let sliderReviews = new Swiper('.reviews__slider', {
    /*
    effect: 'fade',
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    */
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    autoHeight: true,
    speed: 800,
    //touchRatio: 0,
    //simulateTouch: false,
    //loop: true,
    //preloadImages: false,
    //lazy: true,
    // Dotts
    pagination: {
        el: '.reviews__pagging',
        clickable: true,
        bulletActiveClass:'reviews__img-active',
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
            return '<div class="reviews__img-thumbnail ' + className + '">' + (sliderThumbnails[index]) + '</div>';
         },
    },
    // Arrows
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.reviews__next',
        prevEl: '.reviews__prev',
    },
    /*
    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 0,
            autoHeight: true,
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        1268: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 30,
        },
    },
    */
    on: {
        lazyImageReady: function () {
            ibg();
        },
    }
    // And if we need scrollbar
    //scrollbar: {
    //  el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    //},
});
```

Вообщем, миниатюры формируются динамически.